# $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}\implies \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \xi\partial \eta}=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, change-of-variable

I'm reading "Fourier analysis, an introduction" by Elias M. And Rami Shakarchi and in chapter one it said:

The function $u(x,t)$ satisfied the equation $$\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$$

Now let's set $2$ new variables: $\xi=x+t$ and $\eta=x-t$.

We now define the function $v$ such that $v(\xi,\eta)=u(x,t)$.

I understand this but in the book from this they conclude $2$ things that I'm failed to understand how:

$$\dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \xi\partial \eta}=0$$
And $$v(\xi,\eta)=F(\xi)+G(\eta)$$($F,G$ are twice differentiable functions)

How from the change of variables they got to this? I would be happy with either a hint or an answer, thank you very much.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GNUSupporter thank to informing me, I'll be more careful next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint: Use the chain rule**

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta},$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I succeed in the first part thanks to that, but how did they got to the function $v$? I tried to integrate twice but I didn't got to their result

Comment: Imagine you have a function $u(x,y)$ such that $u_x = 0$. This implies that u(x,y) = h(y)$. Does this help?